# Why is my javascript running infinitely?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script in Google Calendar in the console to add all the events from a school calendar to my own calendar. I essentially grab all events on a page, click on them, then on the event page, I want to click add to calendar, then go back, and finish clicking them all on a page.

However, my chunk of code seems to be running infinite times

```
var friendCheckList = document.getElementsByClassName("evt-lk"); 
console.log(friendCheckList.length)

for (var i = 0; i < friendCheckList.length; i++) 
{
    friendCheckList[i].click();
    var possibleReturn = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-imageless-button"); 
    var backArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < possibleReturn.length; i++)
    {
        console.log("Came here with some reason");
        console.log(possibleReturn.length);
        console.log(friendCheckList.length);
        var node = possibleReturn[i];
        if (node.getAttribute("title")=="Back to Calendar") node.click();
    }
};
```

Any idea why this would run infinite times? It's logging "Came here with some reason" 10 13 repeatedly. 10 being the number ofe vents on the page, 13 being the number of "goog-imageless-buttons".

Comment: You have two `var i` statements...

Comment: Aghh, can't believe I didnt' see that.

Comment: Shouldn't that make the program terminate early than expected, not run in an infinite loop?

Comment: @Mike: Actually I'm surprised it causes any problems (in the sample code as given) at all -- I thought JavaScript supported variable shadowing. Anyway, whether it makes it terminate early or never terminate depends on the lengths of `friendCheckList` and `possibleReturn` -- if `possibleReturn.length` is `<=` `friendCheckList.length` the outer loop will never terminate; otherwise, the outer loop will terminate early (except in certain corner cases involving lengths of 0 and 1, etc.).

Comment: @Cameron - Ah yes you're right.  The terminal value of the inner `i` will always be the same, leaving the outer loop never complete.

Comment: @Cameron if `possibleReturn.length` is <= `friendCheckList.length - 1` not `friendCheckList.length` to be accurate. Parent `for` `i++` executes after nested `for` loop, so it is increased in moment of parent `for` condition check, when `i` is equal to `possibleReturn.length + 1` after incrementation.

Comment: @Benio: You are, of course, correct. Good catch! (And sorry for any confusion...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're re-using the `i` variable for the second loop. Use another identifier instead:

```
var friendCheckList = document.getElementsByClassName("evt-lk"); 
console.log(friendCheckList.length)

for (var i = 0; i < friendCheckList.length; i++) 
{
    friendCheckList[i].click();
    var possibleReturn = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-imageless-button"); 
    var backArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < possibleReturn.length; j++)
    {
        console.log("Came here with some reason");
        console.log(possibleReturn.length);
        console.log(friendCheckList.length);
        var node = possibleReturn[j];
        if (node.getAttribute("title")=="Back to Calendar") node.click();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem description

1. Executing nested `for` ends with `i` value equal to `possibleReturn.length`.
2. It looks that it is less than `friendCheckList.length - 1` so you execute parent `for` again.
3. In next execution, `i` is set to `0` by nested `for` to finally end with value of `possibleReturn.length` again and again.

This resetting `i` variable in nested `for` loop cause to never go out of parent loop.

### Solution

Change `i` variable name in seconds (nested) `for`.

### Example

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i < possibleReturn.length; i++)
```

to:

```
for (var j = 0; j < possibleReturn.length; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable for looping in both the outer and inner loop. Every time you start your inner loop you reset the value of i. So as long as the possibleReturn.length < freindCheckList.length the loop will continue.

Try this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < friendCheckList.length; i++) 
{
    friendCheckList[i].click();
    var possibleReturn = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-imageless-button"); 
    var backArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < possibleReturn.length; j++)
    {
        console.log("Came here with some reason");
        console.log(possibleReturn.length);
        console.log(friendCheckList.length);
        var node = possibleReturn[j];
        if (node.getAttribute("title")=="Back to Calendar") node.click();
    }
};
```